# SSRS calendar control in report body

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008. Is there a way to add a calendar control to the body of an SSRS report? My report is exported to Word by the user and the user wants the ability to fill in a date textbox with a date they pick.

The base of the problem is, when the user attempts to manually enter the date; Word uses the "normal" font style (Times New Roman) which causes the report body to have two different fonts.

[baseReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrdIM.png)
[subReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScoA3.png)

Comment: Are you wanting a calendar control to the exported word document?

Comment: Ideally; the user wants it on the word document.  I don't see a problem with it being on the report server page before it is exported if that's possible. The results would be the same.

Comment: just an idea.. why not make the report font the same as what the user users

Comment: What's wrong with using a DateTime Report Parameter datatype?

Comment: @Harry the font the user requested was Calibri, but when they export to Word the default font is Times. They don't want to be bothered with having to change the font when they export.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze I may misunderstand what you're asking about, so ignore me if I'm wrong. If they were to use a report parameter it would set the date for each record to be the date selected in the parameter, right?

The report is some kind of "capacity planning" report where they would like to assign a "work date" to each order. Then's it printed off and handed the orders are handed out to employees based on the "work date" assigned

Comment: @user1603398 We're clearly on different pages here.  You need to provide screenshots of the report to explain what you're talking about  Anyway, with regards to the font.  What is the default font for this user when they create a new document in Word?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze The users decided to go a different direction with the report. I've included the initial images anyway. In the basereport image, the users would click on the hyperlink to populate the subreport image with the necessary data. They would then export to word to manually add the work date in the upper right hand corner.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze 
I understand I could add a Date Time report parameter to the subReport, but the user asked if the subreport could be driven entirely by the basereport and I didn't know if it was possible

Comment: Would the base report have the requiired data for the sub report ?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze yes, that's correct. The only thing it really needs to pass is the order number and the work date. the query in the sub-report will take that to populate everything else.  The initial problem was, they don't like having to manually type in the work date in the subreport. Since the work date is unknown until the user enters it; I don't know of any other way to do this than to put a datetime report parameter on the subreport when it is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tutorials on creating and passing data to Sub reports,

[Wise Owl Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6S8Zzqthsbw)

[TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348(v=sql.100).aspx)

[TechNet_2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581(v=sql.110).aspx)